# How to get around a limit on moving files from Multiple locations to one folder

Tags: batch-file

I have made a simple BAT file with the purpose of moving files from multiple different folders from a list of shortcuts to one folder.

This works well but seems to be limited to about 50 files where I need to do up to 3-4000 ideally, is there a simple way to get around this?

Current code

```
SET source=(***COPY AND PASTE REQUIRED FILES HERE***)
SET destination="***DESTINATION FOLDER***"
for %%i in %source% do XCOPY %%i %destination% /I /F /-Y
```

So example would be

```
SET source=("G://FOLDER1""G://FOLDER2""G://FOLDER3""G://FOLDER4")
SET destination="P://DESTINATIONFOLDER"
for %%i in %source% do XCOPY %%i %destination% /I /F /-Y
```

This is the one and only .Bat file I have ever written. So simple solutions would be hugely appreciate if possible!

Comment: ok, so the code you added here actually works for you?

Comment: Hello - yes it works fine to a point

Answer (score 0):

Comma seperate the paths, remove the parenthesis in the source path, use the double quotes

```
@echo off
Set source="G:\FOLDER1","G:\FOLDER2","G:\FOLDER3","G:\FOLDER4"
Set "destination=P:\DESTINATIONFOLDER"
for %%i in (%source%) do XCOPY %%i "%destination%" /I /F /-Y
```

Comment: One question to this though. Do you actually manually paste the paths into this batch each time? If so, I can give a much better solution to this.